# How can a small change in a code which is never executed make a difference?

Tags: c++, c, linker, gstreamer

I have a **very strange** problem and since it is not possible for me to send code I will try to explain.

This is more like philosophical problem - I hope someone has time/knowledge to think about this.

1) I have project.cpp looking exactly like this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
pthread_t pplayer_thread;
void *play(void*);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pthread_create(&pplayer_thread, NULL, play_cb, NULL);
    usleep(5000000);
    return 0;
}
```

2) pplayer.cpp looking something like this:

```
...
void *play_cb(void *arg) {
    // this starts movie using gstreamer and exits thread
}   
...
```

3) **not_executed**_from_main.cpp looking something like this:

```
...
extern MyClass *myObj; // this is included from .h file
...
MyClass *myObj = NULL;
...
some_function() {
    ...
    myObj = MyClass::createNew(args);
    ...
}
...
```

This is all linked together with various other libraries and ton of garbage, but this is basically what is important.

--> **Problem**:

When I run this, I should see window playing movie clip using gstreamer for 5 seconds -> **BUT I only hear sound!**

--> **Strange thing**:

When I comment the line:

```
myObj = MyClass::createNew(args);
```

and run again --> I see gstreamer window also (everything is fine)

--> **Notes**:

this may have something to do with:

- **linking process** and **nature of MyClass and it's parent class** (my best guess)
- "static" keyword
- "external" keyword
- C and C++ mixing

--> **I ask once more**:

**How can a small change in a code which is never executed make a difference?**

(please help)

Comment: Probable memory issues, check with valgrind

Comment: Try running the program under valgrind and see if there are any stackoverflows/memory leaks/double frees/<insert nasty stuff>.

Comment: There should be no difference. But it seems your `not_executed_from_main.cpp` is making a difference which you are not aware. Could show us the more of this .cpp and .h file?

Comment: Have you tried running your program with Valgrind to see if you have any obvious memory errors?

Comment: I think it has something with undefined behavior (in other code, that you didn't mentioned)

Comment: I suggest you run it in debugger, set breakpoint at this line, and look over stack to see how did the program go to there.

Comment: @asaelr: I tried to debug like this also, but program never gets to this line - this is why it is so strage...

Comment: @Jens: Sorry, but I am not very active here and I have only 11 questions half of which either don't have or can not have definite answer

Comment: Currently, I don't have access to code but in the next 24 hours I will update and hopefully solve this interesting (and very irritating) issue. If solution was found I **will** post it here.

Answer (score 7):

Seems like you need to get familiar with [chaos theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory). In a sufficiently complex system, the slightest change can propagate through any inherent instability to the point of causing a massive difference.

In your case, it can be anything from implicit side-effects of that method, to a memory-related error becoming visible when the layout of the executable code changes.

You should use a debugger to trace your code. Make sure nothing from the supposedly not-executed code is actually executed. Your code may be entering code paths that you mistakenly think are inaccessible, or some other part of your program (e.g. a static initilizer) may be acting up.

[Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) can also be useful if it is available for your platform - it will detect a multitude of memory-related errors, like the one I suspect you have at your hands. Unfortunately it is not very good at detecting errors in the stack - your compiler may be able to help there, though.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably it has to do with stackoverflow. You have something that does some bad thing, addressing things out of bounds or some other undefined behavior and this only triggers (or doesn't) in just some specific configuration. Adding or deleting a variable declaration can be such a thing.

Comment: +1 Adding that code to the binary would shift code that is getting hit by the stackoverflow. I had thought code was protected from data overflowing into it but I doubt that is 100%.

Answer (score 2):

give your example code is not the real code with the problem....

main is not the only entry point where code can start executing, any global objects will execute their constructors which can trigger off all kinds of code.   So perhaps thats some how biting you.

Either debug it, or, perhaps, put messages out to the console to see what paths are executing.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that also (maybe not as good as I should) but I am sure that code *never* gets to this line, so even if program does enter in some constructors (and it does!), I still don't get this...

Comment: there can be all kinds of weird things that go on if you have weird linking problems, memory issues, etc.   Not fun to find....   now if that line of code doesn't get executed, its likely a memory issue,  try putting a different function call there to something else perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

IS your thread using myObj ? If so there could be a race condition between setting myObj to NULL and allocating it again.